# component undefined after calling OnInit() in karma test when using mock services

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a unit test to test an OnInit hook on a angular component. It calls a service on OnInit() and gets templates as follows...

**template.component.ts** is:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import { template} from '../core/model/template';
 import { templateService } from '../core/service/template.service';


 @Component({
    selector: 'app-template',
    templateUrl: './template.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./template.component.css'],
    providers: [templateService ]

})
export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit {

    displayTemplate: template;

    private _isDraftEditing: boolean;
    get isDraftEditing(): boolean {
        return this._isDraftEditing;
    }
    set isDraftEditing(draftediting: boolean) {
        this._isDraftEditing = draftediting;
    }

    getErrorMessage: any;

    constructor(
        private templateService: templateService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isDraftEditing = false;
        this.getTemplateByID('id inserted here from route');

    }


    getTemplateByID(id: number): boolean {
        this.templateService.getTemplateById(id)
            .subscribe(
            getTemplate => {
                this.displayTemplate= getTemplate ;
                if (this.displayTemplate.status.code === 'draft') {
                    this.isDraftEditing = true;
                }

            },
            error => {
                this.getErrorMessage = <any>error;
                console.error(error);
                console.error('getErrorMessage=' + this.getErrorMessage);
            }
            );
        if (this.getErrorMessage != null) { return false; } else { return true; }
    }
```

I have a **template.component.spec** file that does the unit test:

```
 describe('TemplateComponent...', () => {
        let component: TemplateComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<TemplateComponent>;
        let templateService: TemplateService,
            serverservice: ServerService,
            userService: UserService;
        let componentTemplateService: TemplateService;
        let testBedTemplateService: TemplateService;

        beforeEach(() => {
            serverservice = new MockServerService();
            userService = new MockUserService(serverservice);
           TemplateService = new MockTemplateService(serverservice);

        });


        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [TemplateComponent],
                imports: [HttpModule, MdDialogModule, RouterTestingModule],
                schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
                providers: [ServerService, 
                    { provide: TemplateService, useValue: templateService },
                    { provide: UserService, useValue: userService }
                ]
            })
               .overrideComponent(TemplateComponent, {
                    set: {
                        providers: [
                            { provide: TemplateService, useValue: templateService },
                            { provide: UserService, useValue: userService }
                        ]
                    }
                })
                .compileComponents();
        });

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TemplateComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;

            componentTemplateService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TemplateService);
            testBedTemplateService = TestBed.get(TemplateService);


        //mock objects
        it('...', () => {

            fixture.detectChanges();
            fixture.whenStable()
                .then(() => fixture.detectChanges());
            component.ngOnInit();
            expect(component.isDraftEditing).toBe(true);<--this line here: component is undefined!!!

        });
    });
```

Basically I'm injecting a mock template service with a mock template model into the component. That's coming across. However, despite calling OnInit() on the component, isDraftEditing is still undefined. Am I missing something here? From what I've read, I should be able to tap into the components properties, no?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I worked it out myself...

```
it('...', fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.displayOutline = MockTemplateToCreate;
        component.isDraftEditing = true;
        component.ngOnInit();
        discardPeriodicTasks();
        tick(1000);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const el = de.nativeElement;
        const content = el.textContent;
        expect(content).toContain('Save', '"Save"');

    }));
```